# read binary bytes from a jpg file

Tags: c++, file-io

I need to read bytes from a jpg file in c++ so write this codes:

```
ifstream in("1.jpg"ios::binary);
while(!in.eof()){
    char ch = in.get();
}
```

as you know a jpg file consist of 256 difference chars that we can save it's repeat in a a arr.but the problem is that this code that i wrote  read chars in the form of unicode so it consist of 9256 difference char.how can i read from 1.jpg that it wasn't unicode?

Comment: A .jpeg contains bytes, not characters.  Cast the return value of in.get() to (unsigned char).

Answer (score 2):

The `get` function reads unformatted data from the file, it just casts the char it read as an `int`.  Are you seeing data read from the file as different to the actual data in the file?  If you are there could be a problem elsewhere in the code, and you should provide more.

Alternatively you could read chunks of unformatted data using `read`.

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream in("1.jpg", std::ios::binary);

    char buffer[1024];

    while (in)
    {
        in.read(buffer, sizeof(buffer));

        if (in.gcount() > 0)
        {
            // read in.gcount() chars from the file
            // process them here.
        }
    }
}
```